# Show two Kaplan-Meier Estimates at time t are statistically different

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survival, meta-analysis, kaplan-meier

I'm doing a replication of a study. My main concern is that the study I'm replicating is overestimating the risk of disease progression in higher risk patients who receive contemporary treatment. The study reports the 1- and 5-yr probability of disease progression for these patients. These estimates are calculated by evaluating the Kaplan-Meier curve at 1 and 5 years and the confidence interval is generated using the `log` method in R. 119 patients are initially at risk. The number of patients who remain at risk is reported for years 2,4,...8, and 10. So the exact number at risk at year 1 and 5 are unknown.

```
t (yrs)    Prob
  1        17 (10-24)
  5        45 (35-55)
```

Doing some fancy math, I'm able to exactly calculate standard error using the confidence interval and probability alone, in R the formula is this:

```
 se = (log(1-UI) - log(1-Prob))/-qnorm(1 - (1- .95)/2, 0, 1)
```

Apparently, if we assume normality, standard deviation can be calculated by multiplying standard error by the square root of the population size. In which case, a t-test should suffice. I'm uncomfortable with this approach because population size is not static.

I have my own dataset where I have total information. How can I show my own 1- and 5-yr estimates are significantly different than the estimates reported by the study?

Comment: Do the estimates you seek to replicate provide a count of how many are censored vs have an event at each time point? Also, how can survival at 5 years be higher than at 1 year? While mundane, you could ask the authors for their data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a two-sample z-test is the best option. Its assumption is n is largish (~ >30) and standard error is known.

[image: formula]

X's are probability estimates. Sigmas are standard errors of those estimates.